# How to query using expressive syntax in NEST (Elasticsearch)?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am looking to write a small tool to query elasticsearch using NEST APIs and would like to support queries such as `status:[400 TO 499] AND (extension:php OR extension:html)`

I thought that [`SearchQueryString`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/query-string-usage.html) or `SimpleQueryString` API would have helped, but it is not able to get the right results.

```
var r = await this.client.SearchAsync<LogEvent>(s => s
    .Query(q =>
        q.SimpleQueryString(c => c.Query(searchQuery))) // searchQuery -> query string
    .From(from)
    .Size(size)
    .Index("oxyb*")
    .Sort(ss =>
        ss.Descending(f => f.TimeStamp)));
```

Also notice that a similar syntax is supported by elasticsearch API [Query String Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `query_string` query to support those kinds of queries. These map to NEST's [QueryString query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/query-string-usage.html)

```
var from = 0;
var size = 20;
var searchQuery = "status:[400 TO 499] AND (extension:php OR extension:html)";
var response = await this.client.SearchAsync<LogEvent>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .QueryString(c => c
            .Query(searchQuery) 
        )
     )
    .From(from)
    .Size(size)
    .Index("oxyb*")
    .Sort(ss => ss
        .Descending(f => f.TimeStamp)
    )
);
```

which yields

```
POST http://localhost:9200/oxyb*/logevent/_search?pretty=true 
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20,
  "sort": [
    {
      "timeStamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "status:[400 TO 499] AND (extension:php OR extension:html)"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cound use the `QueryString` Query in nest:

```
var r = client.Search<LogEvent>(s => s
    .Query(q => q.QueryString(qs => qs
       .Query("Some String")
       .AnalyzeWildcard(true)
       .DefaultOperator(Operator.And)));
```